# cpearson.com is no longer available

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers, external-links

I came across a reddit post stating that unfortunately Chip Pearson has passed away, [reference](http://www.legacy.com/obituaries/kansascity/obituary.aspx?n=charles-h-pearson-chip&pid=188846047).

With him his site ( [www.cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com) ) went offline. It was a great repository for Excel (VBA) based problems, and was hence cited quite some times. A quick search led me to at least 50 posts. Some of which are now invalidated as they were link only answers more or less.

Perhaps a clean up effort is in order?

Comment: You can flag all the answers as NAA and the community will remove them by voting (Sorry about the technicality, it is sad. RIP)

Comment: @AlonEitan From my experience NAA flags will be declined most of the time for link only answers. VLQ is the more appropriate flag.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser That's fine too - I usually post a comment saying that the link is no longer valid and then flag the answer. It gets deleted almost always

Comment: VLQ is not a flag I can cast

Comment: I checked all the posts, and fortunately there were only one or two answers that got reduced in quality severely, I flagged those as NAA

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Awww.cpearson.com&mixed=0 I see nearly 1.2k posts

Comment: Is the site available on wayback machine? Rather than just removing links to a valuable resource, the community could update.

Comment: That's really unfortunate. His site held a lot of great tutorials and explanations, and all under a free license. If no-one else does, I might host the content again, since it's a pity if it's lost forever

Comment: @TZHX: [yes it is](https://web.archive.org/web/*/www.cpearson.com)

Comment: @BhargavRao, i simply entere cpearson into the searchbar. I bet that leaves out all the link's that have a different text?

Comment: Yep. Use the `url:site_url` always to get all the results.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser: If the answer is truly link-only, I always honour NAA flags.

Comment: The wayback engine has our back: https://web.archive.org/web/sitemap/www.cpearson.com and https://web.archive.org/web/%2a/http://www.cpearson.com%2a. With over 1k posts, perhaps a developer can run a link search-and-replace those links (I'd prefix them with `https://web.archive.org/web/20180407/` to ensure only archived copies from before Mr. Pearson's accident are included). There are nearly 500 captured HTML pages in the `/excel/` path alone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, would there be a straightforward way (script) to replace all instances of the link to cpearson with a web archive version?

Comment: @Luuklag: only a Stack Overflow employee could do that, but the mapping is straightforward; `http://www.cpearson.com/...` becomes `https://web.archive.org/web/20180407/http://www.cpearson.com/...`, and then the wayback engine will redirect the user to the last archived copy of that page, provided that archive was retrieved before Mr. Pearson's car accident.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "died April 19, 2018, at St. Luke's Hospital from severe head injuries received in a car accident on April 8, 2018" So 04-07 was the day before, and should be an okay copy. Is there an easy way to escalate this to an SO employee?

Comment: @Luuklag: I've already poked someone. :-)

Comment: If they're link only they should be deleted anyway (as MartijnPieters said above) If they're not then prepending web.archive can be useful.

Comment: I noticed yesterday the page was down and just thought "that was odd". I had no idea it was like this. Why was the page deleted this quick? Maybe it's a family member wanting to take it down. I'd say find that out first before making copies and keeping his work online. If it is family, try to reason with them. That page had some good code

Comment: I think a more likely scenario was that he was hosting it himself, and the server went offline because of one of many reasons: Turned off by his relatives, internet connection was canceled, utility connection was canceled etc. But as @ErikvonAsmuth was sayin he might be interested in hosting it, perhaps he can find a way to come into contact with his relatives and see if they are willing to make the source files available.

Comment: @Luuklag That could be the reason too. Either way I think it's better to first contact relatives and ask for permission.

Comment: @Andreas It was already hosted under a free license, and the wayback machine has already made its archive. Your intent is good but probably not required.

Comment: @Andreas The Excel MVPs are looking into whether they can get the material and host it.

Comment: @Cindy - do you know which MVP's?  I have be in repeated contact with the Domain Registrar (australia)  and the Web Host (usa) and I have some very relevant information. This is time sensitive (hence my attempt at preserving it here).  I'll host it myself if necessary but it won't get more traffic than on SO anywhere.

Comment: @ashleedawg Re "Which MVPs", this is being discussed on a private MVP-only forum, but if you have info to pass along to them, I'd be happy to forward it there. Easiest way would be to email it to me; steve a-inna-circle pptools dot com

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/ has changed from 404 to *You do not have permission to view this directory or page.*, which is hopefully a good sign.

Comment: @Andre It's back online

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I re-wrote all links to cpearson.com in posts on Stack Overflow to point to https://web.archive.org/web/www.cpearson.com/ - this should pull the last-archived copy of each URL.

May 8th, 2018: aaand UN-rewrote! All archive.org links now point back to the revived www.cpearson.com!

Comment: This is [meta-tag:status-complete], I think.

Comment: As far as I can tell archive.org is missing the majority of the site, hundreds of download-ables in particular - unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Yeah, it's unlikely that archive.org captured downloads, @ashleedawg; also, the last captured version in some cases is a 404 page (prior to the domain disappearing entirely). Answers that depend on either of these will need to be corrected manually.

Comment: There's a move afoot by some of Chip's colleagues to get the site back online and keep it that way for the foreseeable future. Might be best to hold off any major changes to existing URLs until we see what comes of this.

Comment: If it happens, lemme know @steve - I left the urls in a consistent state so that we can rewrite them again if necessary.

Comment: I was hoping you'd done that, @Shog9.  Will post back if the site goes back online.

Comment: @Shog9 The site appears to be back online. _URL Team MOVE OUT!_

Comment: @Braiam more like : status-much-ado-about-nothing ;)

Comment: @Shog9 Glad to see that others have replied with the good news before I learned it.  Thanks all.

Comment: Is this stable, you think @steve? I can re-rewrite the links if so.

Comment: @Shog9 we can safely assume it is, yes. Thanks!

Comment: [It seems to be back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367383/can-we-preserve-chip-pearsons-content-on-stack-overflow/367455#367455).

Comment: Hello, @Shog9, I can confirm that.

Comment: @Shog9, could you please respond to [this meta question about the same subject](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367383/can-we-preserve-chip-pearsons-content-on-stack-overflow)? A user went ahead and decided to (literally) copy the site's most popular page into an SO Q/A.

Comment: What's wrong with Tim's answer, @Cerbrus?

Comment: Oh, what's wrong is that I didn't realise he responded, @Shog9. Whoops.