# Can we preserve Chip Pearson's content on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, opinion-based

Almost anyone who's learned any amount of [VBA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications) in the last 20 years knows the name **Chip Pearson**.

Millions have visited his website, always packed full of easy-to-understand instruction and lateral thinking in the form of countless code samples, hundreds of free downloadable sample files and complete solutions, and superior advice that appealed to novice and veteran coders alike.

Sadly, Chip is no longer with us.  Equally disheartening is that his website's host took down his amazing content almost immediately.

---

I constantly cite cpearson.com when answering questions, such as *just now* with [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50187404/8112776) I was just *attempting* to answer.  I knew of a "perfect resource" with the exact explanation that OP needed, but explained far better than I ever could — but Chip's page is down.

---

**So, I did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50189159/8112776):**

[image: ((image of post & link.))]

I may have bent a rule or two by doing this so I wanted to be upfront about it...  because I would like to add *more* of Chip's content in this manner.

I have been in contact with his [Australian] domain registrar and the [American] hosting service in hopes of reviving the site (taking up a collection if necessary) so the***pure gold*** that *is* cpearson.com doesn't have to disappear, and so that countless others will benefit from the timeless lessons within.

Unfortunately, the host is unable/unwilling to release anything without a court order since (as far as I know) Chip has no surviving next-of-kin except for his elderly parents (who've just lost the last of their 3 children.)  [Archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.cpearson.com) and [cached Google pages](https://www.google.com/search?q=cached%3Awww.cpearson.com) have some pages stored, and I there are probably others (like me) who have a stash of favourite "Chips".  Unfortunately, I've not found a complete source as of yet.

Suddenly I realized there's another [awesome](https://stackoverflow.com) website who *also* has a mission of carrying programming knowledge and to this generation and the next<sup>†</sup>, in an accessible and easy-to-understand format.  *I believe you know which site I'm referring to!*

<sup>†</sup><sub>Stack Overflow's principles surrounding *inclusion*, and our shared responsibility for the next generation of programmers, are discussed in this [video of Jon Skeet's recent visit](https://youtu.be/8UvTdobOiJk) to the Stack Overflow Head Office in New York.</sub>

---

I can guarantee Chip would want nothing more than to have his legacy carry on this form: "**we**", the coding community, "poaching and re-blogging" his code at will (as long as there is **no profit** being made in any form; it is imperative that this content remain both **accessible** and **free**, as it was intended.)

**Here's how I posted the article:**

- I asked & answered the question simultaneously.  The question is a summary of the topics covered in the post.  The primary purpose was to answer [a specific question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50187404).
- I **maintained** as much of the original formatting as possible - while adjusting some parts to Stack Overflow standards and functionality.  (I did include the original section-separator images, and manipulated formatting a little, like centering a few lines. Sorry about that.)
- I immediately marked it as a [**Community Wiki**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/370758), partly because I feel that earning *rep* is inappropriate in this case.
- If possible, I would like to see a **moderator close the Q&A to editing**.  This doesn't prevent changes - it prevents frivolous changes without a mod's assistance (or perhaps there are better ways of preserving solid content?)
- I preserved the author's tagline, giving him credit (although I made a small change to the date, to show the source site's timespan.)
- and finally, partly for the sake of transparency, I timed the post with this one, so as to immediately poll the community's opinion.

### **What does everyone think?  *Is this okay?***

---

Discussion here is encouraged.  If anyone would like to contact me directly (especially any of Mr Pearsons' friends/family who may have some insight) feel free to do so via email at:  `ashleedawg` [image: no-spam].  I am still working with the domain and webhost towards possibly reviving the actual site - but Stack Overflow might be an even more central place to give the next generation continued access to this cached gold.

---

## Update:

**There is a potential solution in the works, to revive cpearson.com with the support of Mrs. Pearson (Chip's mother).  There will likely be a collection taken up towards future funding of the site's hosting fees.** I'll provide more information as it become available.

Chip used to report on this site traffic every couple of years, but he gave up on that in the last years so that he could respond personally to more emails and phone calls.

So here are some stats that even Chip wouldn't have been aware of. In the last couple of years the site was up to 50,000 unique visitors per day, reading 80,000 pages per day. That one visitor every 1.7 seconds. In a year, almost half a million [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) files were downloaded.

All-time traffic today for the site (so far!) **163,300,000 visitors read  287,280,000 pages**. All of this excitement over content consisting of *only* 500 pages and 300 downloadable ZIP files... absolute gold.

Comment: As a suggestion, I would have first posted this and *then*, if the community agreed, posted the actual Q&A. If the community disagrees, you wouldn't have lost time doing the Q&A

Comment: good point - noted.  I was excited to find the content and be able to answer the other question the way I originally intended .  :-)

Comment: [Strongly related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/367314/7296893). I've been thinking about hosting it myself, but I think I'll leave it to the Excel MVPs (per [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367314/cpearson-com-is-no-longer-available#comment585432_367314), they're apparently looking into it, and that might be a great fit, as they're knowledgeable enough to maintain the content).

Comment: i've spoken to the Registrar and the Web Host repeatedly.  I have urgent information for whoever's interested in taking over...  I may be able to get some assistance from  Microsoft's legal team.

Comment: I will host it myself if necessary with my own host  -- or, cpearson.com is up for renewal in a couple weeks (although the registrar indicated they may not be willing to hand it over cheap because of the traffic it generates).  **But where would it get more traffic than SO**

Comment: Protecting the content against edits (so that only elected mods can edit it) sounds too restrictive.

Comment: Has to original page been published under a license that allows duplicating it's content? If not, then posting the content here seems problematic.

Comment: Chip's content has answered so many questions in a concise and technical manner. The knowledge is far superior to what is being presented on the official technical sites at the moment. Is there a concerted effort to dumb down the world? Is deep knowledge dangerous?

Comment: @BDL That's the most critical issue here. Unfortunately, the website (as far as I could browse through it using the wayback machine) does not seem to make any statement about the license at all.

Comment: @BDL and Marco13: [The one relevant page](http://web.archive.org/web/20171015105701/http://www.cpearson.com:80/Excel/LegaleseAndDisclaimers.aspx) I could find via Wayback says: "All of the narrative and textual content on this site, unless stated otherwise, is © Copyright 1997 - 2013 by Charles H. Pearson. All of the formulas and VBA code are explicitly granted to the Public Domain. You may use the formulas and VBA code on this site for any purpose you see fit without permission from me." I wasn't aware of the site until today, so take any implications from this comment with a grain of salt.

Comment: IMHO the site cpearson.com was one of, if not the, most valuable Excel VBA resources on the internet.  I have used it personally and referred others to it countless times.  I would support any and all efforts to preserve its content.  The question is: is SO the right place to preserve that content?  I'm sure some would argue that the Q&A style of SO is not a good fit for at least some of the content.  I, for one, would be happy to see the rules bent to accommodate this content. Hopefully some mods and or staff will chime in with their thoughts.

Comment: @ashleedawg just a suggestion, maybe make the Q CW as well?

Comment: Related: [Chip's obituary](http://www.kccremation.com/ObituaryDetails.aspx?id=23658).

Comment: This is possibly something that Microsoft might want to pursue, they have the resources to handle the legal details.  I have a foot in the door through their MVP program, Chip probably was one as well.  If that sounds like a good idea to you then contact me (email address in my SO profile), anything you know about how to get in touch with the people that manages his estate will be useful.

Comment: @HansPassant I imagine a fair few of the MVPs would be more than happy to get behind this, Chip contributed so much to the VBA world for free, which I can't imagine MS would gloss over if brought to their attention.

Comment: Incidentally, this one page on Chip's site, was  shared by Stack Overflow users in on-site posts & comments an average of 60 times per month for at least the past few years. Sounds pretty relevant to me!

Comment: What everyone needs to realize is that (A) I did not take this matter lightly.. I posted to Stack Overflow after days of [ongoing] phone calls/emails with various firms & individuals regarding permission, legalities, next-of-kin, and Chip's wishes. **The bottom line is, this content WILL be republished - the only question is *WHERE***, and with what level of professionalism, dignity, upkeep, and for what amount of profit, **I would prefer that it was on Stack Overflow so it can  have more traffic than would be possible at any other location plus be protected/maintained forever by all of us.**

Comment: @chrisneilsen I thought it was CW already, I can't see an option to do it now.

Comment: @ashleedawg ok, I haven't asked any Q's so can't comment on their UI (old A's do have a CW checkbox).  Good to hear there will be a future for the content somewhere

Comment: @Hans Passant: Indeed, he was an Excel MVP for nearly two decades.

Comment: The site is no longer down. There is no need to copy the content over. Imo, this should've been discussed ___before___ you posted that Q/A, @ashleedawg.

Comment: [In a car accident](https://www.legacy.com/us/obituaries/kansascity/name/charles-pearson-obituary?id=4470837), 2018-04-19.

Comment: It may be [this user profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9053639/chip-pearson) (though there is only one post (an answer)).

Answer (score 34):

I saw your question as it was posted. I had a couple concerns:

- It seemed a little flashy. Having that banner at the top of the post and fancy dividers was a little distracting. I think that's the first time I've ever seen formatting like that in four years of using SO.
- The question is extremely broad. Unless there is a ridiculous number of "How do I debug VBA" questions and we needed a defacto post to cover them, it doesn't seem like a good fit for the site.
- Linked to the above point, the question seems overly contrived, like the answer was an answer in need of a question.

I'm personally not against consolidating that information here if there's risk of it being lost elsewhere, but it doesn't seem like a great fit for the SE format in its current form.

Comment: Not my content, the format's from the original sight.  The question is supposed to be broad, the answer covers it.  Trust me, that post has helped thousands if not more and it was hard to track down today.  that being said, I appreciate the feedback and the format can be changed.

Comment: The fact that the question is answered doesn't exempt it from site rules. Nor does the fact that it isn't your content, and nor does the fact that it's very helpful. Imho, this is a bad fit for the site. When we had  documentation, it probably could've gone under there, but now it's just plain too broad.

Comment: @ashleedawg "This is a learning site." => "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming.". learning is maybe not a good word, knowledge site is more appropriate. We are not teacher. However this kind of question already exist in other language on SO, it's indeed too broad but sometime necessary.

Comment: @Stargateur: Except learning is *defined* as acquiring knowledge. If the main byproduct of a knowledgebase *isn't* learning, then said knowledgebase has failed. You don't need to be a teacher by profession to teach (aka help people learn). But maybe people associate learning and teaching so closely with a classroom setting that calling Stack Overflow a learning site now carries bad connotations... though fortunately that hasn't stopped the company from adding "Where Developers Learn, Share [...]" to the tagline.

Comment: @BoltClock I think you miss my point, SO is a knowledgebase where people can come to learn from it, but SO itself isn't a learning site. It's like a book, would you say a book is a learning book? Maybe some book could be call like a tutorial book, but SO is not a tutorial site so far I know. So I agree with you, developers learn and share knowledge on SO but this doesn't make it a learning site. SO will be a learning site when we will stop being a Q+A site and go for a forum or something else. SO staff want we help more the newbie, this could become true. But I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: @BoltClock Building up a stigma around "learning" sounds like a great way of unwittingly turning Stack Overflow once and for all into a desolate swamp of insight-free debugging questions. (See also: the dangers of [MCVE-mania](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/361057/2751851).)

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for the second link in your last comment -- instantly favourited.

Comment: @duplode: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/563290

Comment: @BoltClock :D There is some fine irony in all of this...

Comment: @Stargateur I included a link to a video from last week where I referred to this as a learning site

Answer (score 28):

> As long as there is no profit being made in any form

Then you are wrong on Stack Overflow. Stack Exchange is a company solely interested in making profit. The content found on the site is used solely to attract new users and to make profit. If you want the code to be shared without someone making a profit out of it, create your own site and offer it for free.

> Chip has no surviving next-of-kin except for his elderly parents

Contact them if they are the only to inherit; it's now theirs. Tell them how much their passed away son helped you and millions others, without ever wanting something for it. Tell them you want to let his work life on, without financial interest, under the same terms their son did.

I remember a story, about one or two years ago, that explained why Stack Overflow added a `people reached` number to your profile. That was because someone passed away, and it made his parents happy to hear that their son helped so many people with their programming problems. If my son died, it would make me very proud to hear that about him. I'm sure they are willing to help and to let you do that.

If you can't or don't want to afford a server to serve the content, contact me and I'll serve it for free.

Comment: I love the reasoning and sentiment in this answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer however you didn't catch my point about his parents.  They are very elderly/infirm.  I've made attempts at contact, and should not share the result in a public forum.

Comment: Ah sorry, I really misread then @ashleedawg

Answer (score 13):

Part of my motivation for participating on Stack Overflow was to allow my knowledge to outlive my usefulness (or me, as a sentient being, if that's how things fall). But that was a choice *I made* when I stopped putting what I knew in blogs and put it in the site instead, and that's really important.

You can't speak to someone's intent when it comes to artifacts that they created, however useful they are today and likely to remain useful should they endure. I've seen far too many people get mad at the Internet and just yank it all down, as if the rest of the world was an undeserving toddler lacking any grasp over the value they were taking for granted. You really need to know what they *last* intended in the last few seconds of their life and without a will covering it, that's impossible. It has to be up to the next of kin.

I'm glad to see the site back up, I'm glad that we don't have to fix a lot of holes where links to his stuff once lived, and I'm glad that the problem with continuity in general when it comes to mortality in this day and age got some more light - hopefully a *few* of you left a note somewhere about how to renew stuff, or how your family or executor should handle your lasting estate, including creative contributions not intentionally left in the hands of others.

But we can't make assumptions clearly enough to wholesale preserve people's artifacts like that, however noble the intent might be. So what I hope can happen is instead of just saying  ***that was close!*** - those of you that frequent blogs that have become really important places to get answers remind their owners that plans should be in place should the worst happen. I know it's morbid, but it's awareness worth spreading.

I'm glad this worked out the way that it did, and I'm really touched at how much everyone just wanted to help and find a way to make it happen. But let's avoid this in the future by promoting custodianship as a best practice for those that run sites that people come to depend on.

Because, had the domain failed to work out as it did, there'd be little we could do and a very uncomfortable discussion about fair use to be had around the posts it generated.

Answer (score 7):

Having the rules bent a bit to preserve a great piece of knowledge is a thing we could discuss about.

But as far as I can see, duplicating the content here has one major problem: The original text on the website is marked with `(c) Copyright 1997 - 2013 by Charles H. Pearson`. Duplicating it on SO under the CC-BY-SA license is a violation of the copyright and might get SO into trouble. Unless there is some agreement with the current owner of the website, I see no way how the content can be preserved.

Comment: Did you read this [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367383/can-we-preserve-chip-pearsons-content-on-stack-overflow#comment585794_367383) ? Seem that this person take care of this and allow to use the content of the site to anyone.

Comment: @Stargateur the license quoted there is explicitly limited to formulas and VBA code. In other words, Chip thought about this and deliberately decided that he wanted to license the code snippets for people to copy into their work but *not* permit copying his prose. The latter, non-permitted thing is exactly what the OP here has done. Would Chip approve of somebody doing it after his death, when he no longer has any business interest in keeping his work solely on his consultancy's domain to drive traffic? Quite possibly. But that detail is not included in the license he wrote.

Comment: I have been, and am continuing to be, thorough in diligence research and diligence.  Posting this was not something I did lightly, and asking "the SO community was a last minute thought, as my main concern is/was Chip, his wishes, and his family",  As I've stated repeatedly, I am happy to provide more specific information about what is/was being done on a legal front, and the related information have. See my profile for contact info.  It is not a question of whether this content will be published, it is a question of where.

Comment: I understand that you are currently trying to get the legal stuff done. But isn't it a bit strange to first post the content here and then reach out to get the rights for doing it? If I misunderstood your post and you already have the rights to publish it, then you may want to add it to your question.

Answer (score 2):

According to the most recent comment in this discussion [cpearson.com is no longer available](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367314/cpearson-com-is-no-longer-available?noredirect=1#comment585608_367314) the site is back on-line.

Comment: You can easily verify yourself that [cpearson.com](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx) is back online.

Comment: @JohnSlegers  I don't need to - I'm responding to the proposal (Q) about preserving - there's no need, it's back up and apparently being taken care of.

Comment: Aye. This means the whole suggestion of archiving the site on SO (which is a poor fit in the first place) is redundant.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Also: Why did we need two separate threads about this in the first place?

Comment: @BoltClock: Because one user took matters into their own hands, apparently, but I'm [ignorant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50189158/debugging-vba-locating-problems-and-troubleshooting-methods?noredirect=1#comment87445777_50189158) for mentioning that.

Answer (score 2):

Copyright and legal matters aside:

Sharing knowledge Q&A on SO is a bit tricky since your question still needs to live up to the site's standards, even though you actually just want to post an answer. "How do you debug VBA" is far too broad a question.

What you could have done instead here, within the boundaries of SO, was to add the full content to the [VBA tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/vba/info) (with attribution to the original author). Advise about how to attempt to solve basic problems yourself before asking a question is *exactly* what should be on those wiki pages.

You can take your whole answer from the Q&A and make it a debugging chapter of the VBA tag wiki and I very much doubt anyone would object.