# Fixing up now-bad links to use Wayback Machine

Tags: discussion, external-links, clean-up, broken-link

In light of bobpowell dot net having been taken over by malware, as noted in [How to report malware to Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402281/how-to-report-malware-to-stack-overflow), does anyone have any objection to me editing the 26 posts I found with "bobpowell.net" in them and changing the links to [Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/) archive entries?

The 26 posts I'm referring to: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=bobpowell.net - would I have missed any with that search?

---

User Pang was kind enough to point out that I should be searching for the 260-odd results returned by [stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Abobpowell.net](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Abobpowell.net)

It appears that Wayback Machine archives from late 2014 are as the SO authors intended, but there *might* be later ones which are still unaffected. I later found out that Bob Powell passed away in 2014, so the ones from that year will be the latest version.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Abobpowell.net

Comment: @Pang Thanks. That's a nuisance: it makes it an order of magnitude more work.

Comment: Don't forget how [badly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284919/3157076) scripting such edits can go.

Comment: Shog has carried out such an edit perfectly in a way that could be reversed, see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/367342/7296893). Perhaps a staffer can dig up the script he used

Comment: Many of these posts have already been edited - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24375309/revisions

Comment: When including links in posts, perhaps users should be encouraged to create new Wayback Machine or archive.is copies if none already exist, and to link to those instead? As well as situations like this, it would also help avoid the lesser problem of broken links in future.

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica I don't think that's a good idea. Wayback machine links often take noticeably longer to load than the original links and why should the source of the content be deprived of the traffic when it is still available there?

Comment: @Pang The problem with that is that it also includes posts that have already been edited. I tried [`url:bobpowell.net -url:web.archive.org`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Abobpowell.net+-url%3Aweb.archive.org), but for some reason that's still not excluding posts that have been edited.

Comment: @DonaldDuck https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @DonaldDuck That's because you can't exclude special queries like that, so it's searching for things that don't include the _string_ `url:web.archive.org`.

Comment: @MartinSmith Wikipedia does it closely like that by providing both a link to original source AND a link to a cached copy PLUS the date when it was cached. I find this the optimal way but requires more work. "Ideally" for me a platform such as SE should 1) detect links in posts 2) automatically retrieve them when posts is saved and store them "somewhere" (that is safe/permanent) and 3) edit posts to include both links to origin URL and to cached copy.

Comment: Related feature request on MSE: [Automatically have links archived in the Wayback Machine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331125/284827)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are all done as far as I can see.

The replacement links were:

https://web.archive.org/web/20141224180731/http://bobpowell.net/addborder.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20150405144620/http://bobpowell.net/addframes.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20140811074921/http://bobpowell.net/angletext.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141223080308/http://bobpowell.net/animation.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20121006140255/http://www.bobpowell.net/backtrack.htm
https://web.archive.org/web/20141006053603/http://bobpowell.net/capture.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141006051530/http://bobpowell.net/changing_resolution.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20150330022650/http://bobpowell.net/controlaspect.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20140710074441/http://bobpowell.net/coordinatesystems.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141006045615/http://bobpowell.net/creategraphics.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20120520173146/http://www.bobpowell.net/dependencyproperty.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141006052218/http://bobpowell.net/disposing_of_resources.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20140811193726/http://bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141229192143/http://bobpowell.net/drawing_an_image.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141223070404/http://bobpowell.net/dropshadowtext.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141224204810/http://bobpowell.net/embedfonts.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20131213074318/http://bobpowell.net/eventsubscribers.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20120520200821/http://www.bobpowell.net/extents.htm
https://web.archive.org/web/20140811074747/http://bobpowell.net/eyedropper.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145656/http://bobpowell.net/faqmain.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20120716063324/http://www.bobpowell.net/flashbar.htm
https://web.archive.org/web/20120519155512/http://www.bobpowell.net/floodfill.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141006045800/http://bobpowell.net/formattingtext.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20121203143632/http://www.bobpowell.net/fullcustom.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20140714181132/http://bobpowell.net/gdiplus_faq.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141223070416/http://bobpowell.net/generating_multipage_tiffs.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141227173018/http://bobpowell.net/giftransparency.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20130331070932/http://www.bobpowell.net/graphicsstack.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145627/http://bobpowell.net/grayscale.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20140811104050/http://bobpowell.net/halo.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141006051535/http://bobpowell.net/highqualitythumb.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20130130125000/http://www.bobpowell.net/html2aspx.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20140825114946/http://bobpowell.net/image_contrast.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20120419185819/http://www.bobpowell.net/imagefileconvert.htm
https://web.archive.org/web/20140106085952/http://bobpowell.net/imageprocessing.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141223132444/http://bobpowell.net/linear.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141229164101/http://bobpowell.net/lockingbits.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20120718030334/http://www.bobpowell.net/mappingmodes.htm
https://web.archive.org/web/20141230042200/http://bobpowell.net/negativeimage.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20140906075741/http://bobpowell.net/onebit.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20131226033137/http://bobpowell.net/picturebox.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20140906083853/http://bobpowell.net/pgb.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141006053824/http://bobpowell.net/region_from_bitmap.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20140810175854/http://bobpowell.net/ReverseAxisText.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141023005253/http://bobpowell.net/RGBHSB.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20131221083258/http://bobpowell.net/scalepens.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20120519161930/http://bobpowell.net/simpledraw.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141224204707/http://bobpowell.net/singleinstance.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141227200000/http://bobpowell.net/transcontrols.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20130312094930/http://www.bobpowell.net/transformations.htm
https://web.archive.org/web/20141006110746/http://bobpowell.net/texteffects.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20120804065638/http://www.bobpowell.net/toolboxbitmap.htm
https://web.archive.org/web/20141229163946/http://bobpowell.net/understanding_autoscroll.aspx
https://web.archive.org/web/20141229192708/http://bobpowell.net/zoompicbox.aspx